# Put long list of e-mail addresses in multiple-row macro variable

Tags: shell-script, email, macro

I have a list of 20 e-mail addresses that I'm trying to put in a macro variable as multiple rows in a shell script. In "wide" format it works fine and appears as:

```
to_list="email1@test.com,email2@test.com,email19@test.com,email20@test.com"
```

I want something like below, and I'm having trouble with the quotes, commas, and line breaks:

```
to_list="email1@test.com,email2@test.com, \
         .
         .
         .
         email19@test.com,email20@test.com"
```

The usage will be:

```
mail -s "Subject text here." $to_list < body_text.txt
```

According to the syntax the e-mails should be comma separated and only the entire list should be wrapped in quotes as shown in the wide format. However, my test is only sending e-mails to the top row. I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
to_list=(
        "email1@test.com,"
        "email2@test.com,"
        "email19@test.com,"
        "email20@test.com"
        )
mail -s "Subject text here." "${to_list[@]}" < body_text.txt
```

That is using an array, where you were trying to create a string.